# Vim code completion for webapp2,flask,etc

Tags: vim

I'm using [john andersons](http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide#tab-completion-and-documentation) wonderful vim set-up. It has code completion for python enabled. I'm curious if such a solution exists for say webapp2,flask

It's possible i'm not describing this very well so here is an example

when i type:

```
import math
math.a
```

a host of options appears (acos, acosh, etc...)

I would like that same functionally with

```
import webapp2
webapp2.
```

or

```
import flask
flask.
```

Does this exist? I searched and couldn't find. Is it build-able?

Comment: i have webapp2 code completion and debugging in pycharm so it must be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [python-mode plugin](https://github.com/klen/python-mode), it provides this kind of smarter python completion.